# TypeError: prettierApi.resolveConfig.sync is not a function

Tags: webstorm, prettier

I want to reformat with prettier, the error triggered after I press these keys:[image]

This is the first several lines of the error

```
    at PrettierPlugin.resolveConfig (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/prettierJS/prettierLanguageService/prettier-plugin.js:42:48)
    at PrettierPlugin.handleReformatCommand (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/prettierJS/prettierLanguageService/prettier-plugin.js:28:27)
    at PrettierPlugin.onMessage (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/prettierJS/prettierLanguageService/prettier-plugin.js:13:33)
    at Interface.<anonymous>
```

These are prettier, and the other config taken from package.json

```
"
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
```

I've tried downgrading prettier to version 2.8.8, but it still happens.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Webstorm? I had the same issue, I updated Webstorm to the latest version and the error went away.

Comment: yes，I use Webstorm

Comment: @Charlene Try updating. I just had this same error again on a different laptop, updating Webstorm fixed it it looks like they changed some Prettier config settings in the IDE. Click Webstorm -> Check for updates. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

a workaround for me was to create a file watcher in the preferences and trigger prettier on save

[image: setting up custom save rules with File Watchers]